# Check a new list is in order compare to the old list

Tags: c#

Compare 2 lists of strings.

```
var oldList = new List<string>{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg","hhh","iii"};

var newList = new List<string>{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"};//True
var newList2 = new List<string>{"bbb", "ccc", "ddd"};//True
var newList3 = new List<string>{"bbb", "ddd", "fff"};//True
var newList4 = new List<string>{"bbb", "ccc", "aaa", "ddd", "ggg", "fff"};//False
var newList5 = new List<string>{"bbb", "ccc", "aaa"};//False
```

How do compare them in code?

**Edition:**
Not allow Duplication in the new list

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: So you want a `bool` as result?

Comment: Yeah, a bool result. I have tried the sequenceEqual but seem like it is only comparing same count.

Comment: @kingjia: no, the count is only one point, `SequenceEqual` uses the default comparer to compare each element. With strings it works without a problem. But C# is case-sensitive, maybe that explains your issue (or you have invisible characters somewhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following extension, i have tested it with all your lists:

```
public static bool ContainsSequenceSameOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq1, IEnumerable<T> seq2)
{
    if (seq1 == null || seq2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    List<T> l1 = seq1 as List<T>;
    if (l1 == null) l1 = seq1.ToList();

    int indexOf = 0;
    foreach (T obj in seq2)
    {
        indexOf = l1.IndexOf(obj, indexOf);
        if (indexOf == -1) return false;
        indexOf++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Old answer (question changed):

You can use [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
int count = Math.Min(oldList.Count, newList.Count);
bool sameOrder = oldList.Take(count).SequenceEqual(newList.Take(count));
```

**Edit**: according to your revised question and your comment you want to know if the first collection contains the second as "sub-collection". Then you can use this extension:

```
public static bool ContainsSubSequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq1, IEnumerable<T> seq2)
{
    if(seq1 == null || seq2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    IList<T> l1 = seq1 as IList<T>;
    IList<T> l2 = seq2 as IList<T>;
    int c1 = l1 == null ? seq1.Count() : l1.Count;
    int c2 = l2 == null ? seq2.Count() : l2.Count;
    if (c2 > c1) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i <= c1 - c2; i++)
    {
        bool contains = seq1.Skip(i).Take(c2).SequenceEqual(seq2);
        if (contains) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

tested with:

```
var oldList = new List<string> { "foo", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff" };
var newList = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" };

bool containsSubCollection = oldList.ContainsSubSequence(newList); // true
```

Comment: look like the SequenceEqual is not correct for my case.

var oldList = new List<string>{aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff, ggg ,hhh ,iii};

var newList = new List<string>{bbb, ccc, ddd};

It will return false. But for my case I want it to be true

Comment: @kingjia: Why? I have tested it with your strings. For example: `var oldList = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee" };
            var newList = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" };`. Edit: Ok, now i understand. You should have shown this example instead. Do you want to check if one collection contains another? If so, does it matter if the first contains the second or also vice-versa?

Comment: yeah, I have edited the question too.. Sorry about that

Comment: @kingjia: is always the first the one that you want to search or do you also want to find part of the first in the second, so in both directions? Btw, it would be much easier for us if you'd provide real strings like `"aaa"` i nstead of variables like `aaa`. We cannot test that.

Comment: the oldList is always the one to compare with the new lists.

Comment: for newList3, it returns false. Look like the method you provided is only take newlist.count() from the oldList, and if the objects taken in the new list are not in order, it will return false.

Comment: @kingjia: i haven't seen that you have provided those sample lists. Ok, then you are not looking for a "sub-collection" but if all of list2 are in list1 in the same order. What if there are duplicates?

Comment: No duplication in the new List

Comment: @kingjia: have a look at my answer. I'm using `List.IndexOf` with thew overload that takes the start-index.

Answer (score 0):

Compare both list up to the last item of the shorter list. If until that position all items are equal, then the `newList` is correct.

```
var oldList = new List<string>{aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff, ggg ,hhh ,iii};
var newList = new List<string>{bbb, ccc, aaa, ddd, ggg, fff};
int lenghtOfShorterList = Math.Min(oldList.Count, newList.Count);

for(int i = 0; i < lenghtOfShorterList ; i++)
{
    if(oldList[i] != newList[i])
    {
        return; //list not correct
    }
}
return; //list correct
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know if subsequence is in the same order, regardless of whether elements go one by one:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var oldList = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii" };

        var newList = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" };//True
        var newList2 = new List<string> { "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" };//True
        var newList3 = new List<string> { "bbb", "ddd", "fff" };//True
        var newList4 = new List<string> { "bbb", "ccc", "aaa", "ddd", "ggg", "fff" };//False
        var newList5 = new List<string> { "bbb", "ccc", "aaa" };//False

        Console.WriteLine("Expected: true, Actual: " + IsCorrectOrder(oldList, newList));
        Console.WriteLine("Expected: true, Actual: " + IsCorrectOrder(oldList, newList2));
        Console.WriteLine("Expected: true, Actual: " + IsCorrectOrder(oldList, newList3));
        Console.WriteLine("Expected: false, Actual: " + IsCorrectOrder(oldList, newList4));
        Console.WriteLine("Expected: false, Actual: " + IsCorrectOrder(oldList, newList5));
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public static bool IsCorrectOrder(IList<string> orderedSequence, IList<string> testedSequence)
    {
        var lastFoundIndex = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < testedSequence.Count; i++)
        {
            var testedElement = testedSequence[i];
            var testedFound = false;

            // finding first matching item in ordered sequence

            for (var j = lastFoundIndex; j < orderedSequence.Count; j++)
            {
                var orderedElement = orderedSequence[j];
                if (orderedElement == testedElement)
                {
                    lastFoundIndex = j;
                    testedFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (testedFound)
                continue;

            // if there is no such element, then the order is not correct

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```